# PrestaShop API memory limit

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am using PrestaShop 1.5 and trying to make this API (webservice) call:

```
example.com/api/order_histories?schema=blank
```

However it returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of {some numbers} bytes exhausted (tried to allocate x bytes).

While invoking this URL:

```
http://example.com/api/categories?schema=blank
```

works just fine.

So I gradually increased my php.ini `memory_limit` parameter. Initially it was set to 32M, so I tried to bumped it up to 64M, 128M, until all the way up to 1024M. I also tried to set it up to 2048M, but since I only have 1GB RAM, 2048M will pretty much crash the server.

Before I am looking further into the code, I just want to know whether anyone else experience this kind of problem with PrestaShop (1.5.4), and if yes what was/is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem before.

There's a bug in class `WebserviceRequest` which instantiate every object of this class to get a blank schema. So when calling a class like categories that contains a few entries there's no problem. But when calling a class like order_histories that contains thousands of entries it will load thousand objects in memory and crash.

But I can't remember which method was causing this bug. You should start debuging from method `executeEntityGetAndHead` and check if method `getFilteredObjectList` is called.

---

**EDIT:**

The method `getFilteredObjectList` has been updated [on github](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-1.5/blob/master/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php):

```
public function getFilteredObjectList()
{
    $objects = array();
    $filters = $this->manageFilters();
    /* If we only need to display the synopsis, analyzing the first row is sufficient */
    if (isset($this->urlFragments['schema']) && in_array($this->urlFragments['schema'], array('blank', 'synopsis')))
        $filters = array('sql_join' => '', 'sql_filter' => '', 'sql_sort' => '', 'sql_limit' => ' LIMIT 1');

    $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['params'][] = $filters['sql_join'];
    $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['params'][] = $filters['sql_filter'];
    $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['params'][] = $filters['sql_sort'];
    $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['params'][] = $filters['sql_limit'];
    //list entities
    $tmp = new $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['className']();
    $sqlObjects = call_user_func_array(array($tmp, $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['retrieveMethod']), $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['params']);
    if ($sqlObjects)
    {
        foreach ($sqlObjects as $sqlObject)
        {
            if ($this->fieldsToDisplay == 'minimum')
            {
                $obj = new $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['className']();
                $obj->id = (int)$sqlObject[$this->resourceConfiguration['fields']['id']['sqlId']];
                $objects[] = $obj;
            }
            else
                $objects[] = new $this->resourceConfiguration['retrieveData']['className']((int)$sqlObject[$this->resourceConfiguration['fields']['id']['sqlId']]);
        }
        return $objects;
    }
}
```

With this modification, if we ask a blank schema a `LIMIT 1` is added to the query so that only one object is loaded from database.

Comment: Did you solve this bug ? I'd love to know how did you come up with a solution. In the meantime i will try your proposed solution.

Comment: I did but it was in another company and I don't have the code anymore... Good luck with that ;)

Comment: Holy mother of all good thing, it seems that you pointed me at the right direction. The solution to this problem is by adding "LIMIT = 1" to the query if it request a blank schema as mentioned in this github log: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/b51641ca49aff8ffdc18d41e0676d339939345e8

Comment: Your answer (at the moment) might not 100% accurate, so if you can edit it i will set it as correct answer. Cheers....!

Comment: Ahah seen it at the same time, was on github too ;). I will edit my answer

Comment: as promised, upvoted & accepted as correct answer. Thanks, i owe you one..!